# Java CDI can't find my alternative beans

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi

I have the following interface that extends an third part interface:

`public interface TypedExampleGenerator<T extends EntidadeBase> extends ExampleGenerator {}`

In all project I am using CDI to instantiate the right type of bean as the following:

```
public class GenericCrudBO<T extends EntidadeBase> implements CrudBO<T>{
   @Inject
   private Instance<CrudDAO<T>> dao;
}

public interface CrudDAO<T extends EntidadeBase> extends Serializable{...}
```

with a generic default implementation for most cases:

```
@Default
public class GenericCrudDAO<T extends EntidadeBase> implements CrudDAO<T>{...}
```

and specific alternative implementations for specific cases:

```
@Alternative
public class UsuarioDAO extends GenericCrudDAO<Usuario>{...}
```

It is working nice on my BO and DAO layers, but when I try to do the same with the TypedExampleGenerator interface, looks like CDI can't 'understand' my alternative beans as alternatives. Here's the stacktrace:

```
'org.jboss.weld.exceptions.AmbiguousResolutionException: WELD-001318 Cannot resolve an ambiguous dependency between [Managed Bean [class br.com.logtec.dao.example_generators.FornecedorExampleGenerator] with qualifiers [@Default @Any], Managed Bean [class br.com.logtec.dao.example_generators.FuncionarioExampleGenerator] with qualifiers [@Default @Any], Managed Bean [class br.com.logtec.dao.example_generators.UsuarioExampleGenerator] with qualifiers [@Default @Any], Managed Bean [class br.com.logtec.dao.example_generators.DocumentoExampleGenerator] with qualifiers [@Default @Any], Managed Bean [class br.com.logtec.dao.example_generators.ClienteExampleGenerator] with qualifiers [@Default @Any], Managed Bean [class br.com.logtec.dao.example_generators.GenericExampleGenerator] with qualifiers [@Default @Any], Managed Bean [class br.com.logtec.dao.example_generators.ContadorExampleGenerator] with qualifiers [@Default @Any]]
```

there are two examples of implementations, one generic and one specific:

```
@Default
public class GenericExampleGenerator implements TypedExampleGenerator<EntidadeBase>{...}

@Alternative
public class UsuarioExampleGenerator implements TypedExampleGenerator<Usuario>{...}
```

the alternatives are declared in my beans.xml as you can see:

```
<class>br.com.logtec.dao.example_generators.ContadorExampleGenerator</class>
<class>br.com.logtec.dao.example_generators.FornecedorExampleGenerator</class>
<class>br.com.logtec.dao.example_generators.FuncionarioExampleGenerator</class>
<class>br.com.logtec.dao.example_generators.UsuarioExampleGenerator</class>
<class>br.com.logtec.dao.example_generators.DocumentoExampleGenerator</class>
<class>br.com.logtec.dao.example_generators.ClienteExampleGenerator</class>
```

Just to make thing clear, every entity in the project extends EntidadeBase.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution by replacing this:

```
@Default
public class GenericExampleGenerator implements TypedExampleGenerator<EntidadeBase>{...}
```

with this:

```
@Default
public class GenericExampleGenerator<T extends EntidadeBase> implements TypedExampleGenerator<T>{...}
```